How can I update running(activated) system extension in mac?
Now we are trying to update our security solution. The solution is built with endpoint security extension, and it's already distributed for all clients, and we want to update them.
But it seems like updating the existing system extension is a hard work.
Below are the tasks that we did.

Modify Extension Manager class

- (OSSystemExtensionReplacementAction)request:(OSSystemExtensionRequest OS_UNUSED *)request actionForReplacingExtension:(OSSystemExtensionProperties *)existing withExtension:(OSSystemExtensionProperties *)extension
{
    NSLog(@"Got the upgrade request (%@ -> %@); answering replace.", existing.bundleVersion, extension.bundleVersion);
    os_log(OS_LOG_DEFAULT, "Got the upgrade request (%@ -> %@); answering replace", existing.bundleVersion, extension.bundleVersion);

    return OSSystemExtensionReplacementActionReplace;
}

We modified OSSystemExtensionReplacementAction to replace current extension program.

Modify CFBundleVersion / CFBundleShortVersionString

<key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
<string>1.3</string>
<key>CFBundleVersion</key>
<string>2</string>

we modified version codes in the info.plist file to get updated

Checked System settings

We also checked for system settings. Becuase there could be "Allow extension" alike buttons enabled. But there were none buttons enabled related to system extensions.
We tried all of them, but existed activated extension is still running, and version is not updated

What could be the reason?
